# Can I run a CMD command without a new line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run the pause command without it displaying `Press any key to continue . . .` AND without creating a new line? I tried out the method someone suggested for echoing text without a new line, but that didn't work for me.

`pause>nul` is as far as I've gotten, but that creates a new line.

Here's an example:

```
This is some sample text.
```

The script pauses until a key is pressed.

And then it processes the rest:

```
This is some sample text.Here is the rest.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update your question with an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, commands are built in to the cmd executable and their behavior can't be changed. You *can* however, simulate the command output with an echo (or a `<nul set /p =` in your case).

```
@echo off

REM Write the same message that pause prints, but do not include a newline
set /p "=Press any key to continue..." <nul

REM Pause without output
pause >nul

REM Prove that we're still on the same line
echo This is on the same line
```

Comment: To clarify, the OP claims that "`pause>nul` ... creates a new line", but it does not. `echo` writes a newline, so the OP can use the prompt from `set /p "=text to write" <nul` to echo text without a newline.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I was using `echo`. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I'm in a fluke again. I'm at the bottom of the CMD screen. I'd like to fill the entire window with characters, but CMD wants to add a new line below. [Click here for a few screenshots](https://postimg.org/gallery/2ocmqfx7g/)

Comment: @ditheredtransparency you have now changed the scope of your original question.  Either update your question or accept this as the answer to your question and start a new question.

Comment: Alright Squashman. Since it bothers you so much, and since this update is drastically different from my original question, I will accept the answer I have been given, and create a new question based off my update.